# When is a question considered a Data Science question and when is considered a coding question more appropriate for StackOverflow?

Tags: discussion

The title is self explanatory: where to draw the line between data science specific questions, suited for the *Data Science SE*, and coding questions that are more appropriate for *StackOverflow*?

For example, consider the question *"How to use Pandas in conjunction with scikit-learn?"*. Which category should this belong to?

Answer (score 6):

I think that the following simple logic should be applied. If a question is in its **essence** more about data science (models, approaches, methods, tools, etc.), where a programming language represents just a *context*, then such question fits *Data Science SE* site better. If, alternatively, the situation is reversed, where programming (coding) aspects are the core of the question, while data science represents context, such question should be asked on (or migrated to) *StackOverflow* (with a corresponding tag, i.e. `r`, `python`). I think that purely a fact of using a language, popular in data science community, as a context, does not justify a question to be considered on-topic on *Data Science SE* site. We can find an example of such situation in [this purely R programming question](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/6773/2452).

It is important to ask questions on the most appropriate site, as, per SE rules, if a question is answered, it cannot be migrated to the other site, even, if that site is the most appropriate (other rules also apply in this case). There are other negative potential side effects of migration as well.

Comment: Why can't questions be migrated SO? It because DS is beta? Posts can move between CV & SO, so this has been frustratingly confusing (a large % of the DS R posts I've seen belong on SO).

Comment: @hrbrmstr: I (then non-moderator) have asked [the similar question](http://meta.datascience.stackexchange.com/q/2150/2452) a while ago. If you think a question belongs to another SE site, you can flag that question for moderators' attention and we will be happy to do that for you, if it is warranted.